# spring integration bridge direct channel to queue Channel

Tags: spring, spring-integration, bridge

At unit test time, I try to bridge the Spring Integration default channel to a queued channel, since I want to check the correctness of the amount of message flow into this channel.

```
<int:filter input-channel="prevChannel" output-channel="myChannel">
<int:bridge input-channel="myChannel" output-channel="aggregateChannel">
// the reason I have above bridge is I want to check the amount of message after filter.
// I cannot check prevChannel since it is before filtering, and I cannot check aggregateChannel 
// because it has other processing branch

// in test xml I import above normal workflow xml and added below configuration to 
// redirect message from myChannel to checkMyChannel to checking.


<int:bridge input-channel="myChannel"
            output-channel="checkMyChannel"/>

<int:channel id="checkMyChannel">    
    <int:queue/> 
</int:channel>
```

I autowired checkMyChannel in my unit test
but checkMyChannel.getqueuesize() always return 0.

Is there sth I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this fixed, I have to declare myChannel to be a publish-subscribe-channel

[How to test Spring Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219589/how-to-test-spring-integration)
This one helps, for my case there is a race condition since.
"A regular channel with multiple subscribers will round-robin ..."

Answer (score 0):

You missed to share test-case with us. We don't have the entire picture. And looks like you have a race condition there. Someone polls all your messages from the `checkMyChannel` before you start assert that `getqueuesize()`.

In our tests we don't use `<poller>` for such a cases. We use `PollableChannel.receive(timeout)` manually.

Comment: Your code doesn't work, because I don't know what is `gateway.publish()` and you haven't explained why do you need `<int:poller>`

Comment: Wow! There is `aggregateChannel` as well. So, you have two `<bridge>` for the same `myChannel`, which looks like `DirectChannel` with the default round-robin balancer. So, now your config is more complicated. Not sure which help are you seeking here, but it is difficult to help someone who doesn't cooperate...